# How does Guild Wars 2 reward teamplay in combat?

Tags: guild-wars-2

Guild Wars 2 rewards other aspects of teamplay, like for example reviving a downed player which gives you some experience.

It has been explained already that Guild Wars 2 has a [combo system](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/82168/how-do-combos-work-in-guild-wars-2), between players: some skills can interact with others.

What are the rewards, the incentives Guild Wars 2 gives for active teamplay in combat, typically via the use of combos, if any?

Is there a bonus in experience? A bonus in damage?

Comment: It's not so much a "rewards for teamplay" as it is a "no penalties for having to share kills", as in you can't kill steal, or have to camp harvesting nodes, etc

Comment: What about WvW? PvP? Kills are definitely not shared.

Comment: It's possible for two or more players to get loot after killing one, so they're shared the same way PvE kills are. This is my subjective experience though, I only do WvW for my monthly, so if you have some more concrete source, feel free to correct me.

Comment: Maybe finishes are personal, since after a finish the other guy will be dead and not just downed, but I've seen multiple people finish the same opponent?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As already mentioned, combos are a powerful incentive if correctly used - for example, you can keep up 25 might stacks on the entire group with a minimal amount of players blasting through a fire field. This is like having an extra set of power/malice gear.

Reward-wise, more players means more kills without a decrease in experience or rewards. It's probably more than just a linear progression, since you won't waste time dodging (not to mention you'll never die again).

Also, hearts are completed much faster. To give an example, one of the hearts in Caledon Forest allows you to progress by killing undead. Those undead are spawned by pulling their hands - which are instanced. A solo player can pull a hand, kill the spawn, then move on to the next hand (2 progression points, one for the hand and one for the kill). A party of three can each pull the same hand (instanced), then aoe on the three spawns - not only will they kill faster, each of them will get double progression (1 point for the pull, 1*3 for the kills). While the solo player will have to stay around for a while, the group will pull the 4-5 hands in the area around them and be done with the quest.

Answer (score 2):

There is only the [outcome of the combo](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Combo).
There are also [achievements for 'team play'](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Community) and there is one specifically for doing combos with other players also called "Teamwork Gets It Done".